# SSIS Data Migration/Daily copy: Parent + Child then many Grandchild tables

Tags: parent-child, ssis

I've read this link here, but this guy is doing a one off copy from 1st normal form to 3rd, so that's not what I'm doing: [StackOverflowPosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597896/ssis-data-migration-split-flat-table-into-parent-child-grandchild-tables)

I am going from 3rd normal form to 3rd normal form, pretty much the same design, on a daily basis, only copying hte new data.

Example Data

## Parent

- ParentId
- Created Date

## Child

- ChildId
- Created Date
- FK_to_ParentId
- Child Data

## GrandChild1

- GrandChild1Id
- FK_to_ChildId
- GrandChild1Data

## GrandChild2

- GrandChild2Id
- FK_to_ChildId
- GrandChild2Data

So Far, I have

- A DataFlow that will pull back all
  the Parents after a certain Date.
- A DataFlow that will pull back all
  the    Child Tables created after a
  certain    date, with a lookup to
  find the 'new'    FK in the new
  database.
- Now I need to    pull back
  grand child1 and so on, but    I
  don't want to pull them'all' back,
  do a look up, and throw away the ones
  I already have, I only want to pull
  back the ones I need.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've just used a inner join using Date and time where available, but when I get the data, I have to do a lookup to find the 'new' FK Id to put in the child & grand child tables. Which means the data for Parent, and Child still needs to contain the 'old' ID, but that is ok. so for a Child table, you end up with something that looks like this:

Data Source -> Lookup using the current FK on the parent table to find the new parent's PK, adding in what makes it unique [replace the FK with the PK you just found] -> data store.